# How to set or clear value of material-ui Input in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am unable to clear the value of a material-ui Input using refs, not state.

I've tried both types of refs that I know about: 
ref={this.input}
 - and -
ref={el => (this.input = el)}

but neither seems to work w/ a material-ui Input

the following similar questions did not help:
[How to get input value of TextField from Material UI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52571256/how-to-get-input-value-of-textfield-from-material-ui)
[Clear and reset form input fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43922508/clear-and-reset-form-input-fields)
[Clear an input field with Reactjs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38731271/clear-an-input-field-with-reactjs)
[how to set Input value in formField ReactJs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56851242/how-to-set-input-value-in-formfield-reactjs)

Here's a snippet of my React JSX for the input & button:

```
    <Input
      type="text"
      id="name"
      inputComponent="input"
      ref={el => (this.name = el)}
    />
    <Button
      variant="contained"
      onClick={this.handleClear}
      className="materialBtn"
    >
      Clear
    </Button>
```

And the event handler that I expect should clear the input value:

```
    handleClear() {
      this.name.value = "";
    }
```

I can make the code work fine using a standard HTML5 input, but *not* with a material-ui input, which is a requirement of this project. Additionally, this element's value is NOT in react state and I am not looking for a solution that requires using state -- I need to keep this piece as an uncontrolled component.

What am I missing w/ regard to material-ui? I have combed their docs/api but haven't found anything that suggests it needs to be handled differently from a standard input. thanks

Here's an example on CodeSandbox showing the failure w/ a material-ui input and success w/ an HTML5 input:
https://codesandbox.io/s/fancy-frost-joe03

Comment: What is the version of Metherial UI?

Comment: I'm using material-ui/core 4.3.0.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I figured it out, you are using the wrong prop for the ref.
You should be using `inputRef` prop.
Here is the correct version,

```
<Input
    type="text"
    id="name"
    inputComponent="input"
    inputRef={el => this.name = el}           
/>
<Button
    variant="contained"
    onClick={this.handleClear}
    className="materialBtn"
>
 Clear
</Button>
```

```
handleClear() {
      this.name.value = "";
    }
```

The reason is that the Material Input component creates an element with the following structure,

```
<div class="MuiInputBase-root MuiInput-root MuiInput-underline">
<input class="MuiInputBase-input MuiInput-input" id="name" type="text" value=""></input>
</div>
```

So, using `ref` would reference the root element which is `<div>`. So, they created a separate prop called `inputRef` to reference the child element `<input>`.

I updated your codesandbox.io code and saved it. Check out the full working code here,

https://codesandbox.io/s/elastic-dhawan-l4dtf

Comment: Wow, it never occurred to me that Material-UI prevents a React ref from working as designed. It would have been helpful if the documentation had gone to the trouble of stating that inputRef must be used *in place of* a standard React ref. Thank you for your insight.

Comment: @Coder True, it is a bit unconventional. I happened to figure it out by looking at the API [here](https://material-ui.com/api/input/). The reason is that the Material Input component creates an element with the structure ```<div><input></input></div>```, so using ref would reference the root element which is <div>. So, they created a separate prop called inputRef to reference the child element <input>. I have updated the answer with this explanation

Comment: I keep forgetting to use inputRef as opposed to ref.

Answer (score 1):

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
    
import { Button, Container, InputBase } from '@material-ui/core'


const ClearText = ()=> {
    const [text , setText] = useState("")
}

const clearTextField = () => setText("")

    return (
        <Container>
        <InputBase 
        value={text ? text : ""}
        onChange={(e)=>setText(e.target.value)}
        />


        <Button onClick={clearTextField} > Clear </Button>
        </Container>
    )
};

export default ClearText;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code is a lot more helpful when it is accompanied by an explanation. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please [edit] your question and explain how it answers the specific question being asked. See [answer].